# Datas anteriores

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu estou fazendo relatório em que preciso pegar sempre a data de cadastro de clientes num mês anterior.
Exemplo: Estou no mês de Dezembro de 2017, eu quero pegar os clientes que foram cadastrado de 1º de Novembro 1 até o último dia de Novembro;
E quando eu tiver em Janeiro de 2018, quero pegar os clientes que foram cadastrados do dia 1º de Dezembro até o último dia.

Comment: Qual a estrutura da sua tabela?

Comment: As tabelas são feitas pelo Entity Framework

Comment: Poste o que vc já tem de código, html, css, js etc. isso ajuda a te responder corretamente.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para selecionar os clientes cadastrados no mês anterior seu código ficará próximo aos exemplos abaixo:

**Entity Framework**

```
db.Usuarios.Where(x => x.DataCriacao.Month == DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month);
```

**SQL Server (T-SQL)**

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Tabela 
WHERE 
    Canal = 'FILIAIS' 
    AND Email like '%@%' 
    AND DATEPART(mm, DataCadastro) = DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE())
    AND DATEPART(aaaa, DataCadastro) = DATEPART(aaaa, DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Eu fiz algo semelhante assim: AGE.DataCadastro BETWEEN GETDATE()-30 AND DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,-1, GETDATE()),-1)
So que não esta pegando da forma que eu quero

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo utilizando SQL Server

Comment: Vou copiar meu where.. rs

WHERE Canal = 'FILIAIS'  AND Email is not null AND Email <> '' AND Email like '%@%'  AND AGE.DataCadastro BETWEEN GETDATE()-30 AND DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,-1, GETDATE()),-1)

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, deixei somente o LIKE com @, ele já exclui os outros filtros.

Comment: Esse seu DATEPART('mm', AGE.DataCadastro)
Esse MM nao seria sem aspas simples? Para passar o MM ( mes)?

Coloquei sem passar com aspas simples e funcionou!
Obrigado amigo!.

Comment: So teve um pequeno problema, no seu exemplo ele também pegou do ano de 2016, tem como ser somente desse ano?

Comment: Exato, fiz os ajustes.

Answer (score 0):

Se fizer por query isso aqui resolve, sempre vai pegar a data início e data fim do mês anterior ao atual.

```
Select Convert(DateTime, Convert(Varchar(6), DateAdd(Month, -1, GetDate()), 112) + '01', 103) -- data inicio 
Select DateAdd(Day, -1, DateAdd(Month, 1, Convert(DateTime, Convert(Varchar(6), DateAdd(Month, -1, GetDate()), 112) + '01', 103))) -- data fim
```